# How do I root my Nexus 7?

Tags: rooting, nexus-7

I am wanting to gain root privileges on my Google Nexus 7 tablet, running Android 4.1-4.2.1. How can I do this?

Comment: I took the freedom to add your Q to our [Rooting Index](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/) -- see also the tag-wiki for the "rooting" tag ;) Besides: Did you know that there was already a "Nexus 7 rootkit" mentioned?

Comment: @LiamW I found this quite useful. I'm not going to do it though, as I don't want to lose my current memory. Do you know if it is at all possible to root a Nexus 7 without losing the memory, or at least a way to backup the memory to restore later?

Comment: @Fogest See edit to use adb backup :)

Comment: @LiamW I was not telling you off -- sorry if you got that expression! It was meant as a thumbs-up and giving a hand. Good guide you wrote! So it needed to be linked in the first place to look for good guides on rooting.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The Nexus 7 is probably one of the easiest Android devices to root - and all you need is the Android SDK (and 2 downloads).

**Step 1**

Install the `adb` and `fastboot` commands. On Ubuntu:

`sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot`

On Windows you should download the Android SDK, however you can just download this zip which contains the `adb`, `fastboot` and dependencies.

**Step 2**

On your Nexus 7, go to `System Settings->Developer Options->Check USB Debugging` (You may need to slide the toggle switch in the action bar to on). If you do not see the USB Debugging option, go to `System Settings->About Tablet->Tap on 'Build Number' 7 times`.

Connect your Nexus to your computer.

**Step 3**

*Make sure the drivers have downloaded and installed if you're on Windows - Windows Update should automatically find them.*

Once connected, open up a terminal window (Windows: Win+R, type `cmd` press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Ubuntu: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) and navigate to where you have unzipped the fastboot & adb programs (no need to do this on linux - they are in the path).

**Step 3.5**

Type `adb backup -all -nosystem` to backup your userdata to the `backup.ab` file.

**Step 4**

Type `adb reboot bootloader`.

**Step 5**

When the Nexus 7 has rebooted into fastboot mode, type `fastboot oem unlock`. Read the information on the device, and touch the `Yes` option. Your bootloader will be unlocked. **This will erase *all* userdata!**

**Step 6**

Download the [latest TWRP recovery image](https://dl.twrp.me/flo/). Save it in the same location as the fastboot binary. Issue the `fastboot flash recovery twrp.img` command to flash this recovery image.

**Step 7**

From the fastboot menu (green robot on its back with the cover open), use the volume keys to cycle through the options `start`, `restart bootloader`, `power off`, to `recovery mode`.  Push the power key to select recovery mode.
You'll see the google logo with an unlocked padlock, and then the TWRP splash screen for about 45 seconds. Then TWRP asks "keep system read-only?"  Instead of tapping on "no,"  swipe the swiper to allow these modifications.
This shows you the TWRP menu, 8 big buttons.  Tap on `Advanced`.  On the next menu, tap on `ADB Sideload`.

Download the latest [SuperSU](http://download.chainfire.eu/supersu) zip file and save it to the same location as adb and fastboot. **DON'T UNZIP IT.**

**Step 8**

On the Nexus 7, swipe the swiper to prepare it to sideload.
Issue the command `adb sideload CWM-SuperSU-v0.99.zip`, which takes about a minute, and then tap the `reboot` button.  This may take several minutes and several reboots, so don't worry.

The Nexus 7 is now rooted!

**Step 9**

Type `adb restore <backup file made in 3.5>` to restore from a backup.

Comment: There is a step missing before 5, where you backup the userdata.

Comment: @ott Fixed... ;)

Comment: What does the backup save. Does it save things like music, apps/appdata? What specifically is backed up?

Comment: @Fogest Apps and appdata

Comment: @LiamW So, if I were to do this, and recover the backup, would my device appear like nothing has changed, or are there some things lost? I am just really busy lately and would rather not do this now, if I will have to reconfig a lot.

Comment: The link to the TWRP image doesn't work anymore (404).

Comment: TWRP link still doesn't work, but you can get it for the nexus 7 (2013 WiFi) here: http://www.teamw.in/project/twrp2/193

Comment: ERROR: 
cmuench-air:platform-tools cmuench$ adb sideload CWM-SuperSU-v0.99.zip
loading: 'CWM-SuperSU-v0.99.zip'
error: closed

Comment: Chris, just before that command, swipe the swiper on the Nexus 7.  I've edited step 8 to reflect this.  (Also use the name of the .zip file that *you* downloaded.  Mine had about a dozen numbers in it, for instance.)

Comment: I know this is an old post, but I get to step 7 and don't get the TWRP splash screen. Could this be a versioning issue (my Nexus is the old 2012 model)