# rooting android 4.4 on nexus 7 2012

Tags: rooting, nexus-7, 4.4-kitkat

I have just updated my rooted nexus 7 2012 running android 4.3 to android 4.4. How do I root the new version? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same way you root any other version on a Nexus device. It has an unlockable bootloader, so the specific version of Android installed doesn't really matter. [How do I root my Nexus 7?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37760/how-do-i-root-my-nexus-7)

Comment: @eldarerathis: Nvm, I have rooted my nexus 7 successfully. Thanks!