# Rooting a Nexus7 (2012) without installing a custom ROM

Tags: rooting, nexus-7

I have a Nexus7 Tablet (2012) with Android 4.4.2. I'd like to root it, so that I can use some Apps, that need superuser rights.

I just found tutorial that explain how to root this device using a Custom ROM. Is it possible to root **without installing** a Custom ROM? Why is it not possible to just install "su" on the Tablet as I did with my Phone?

Comment: Have you seen [How do I root my Nexus 7?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/37760/16575) The description there does not use a custom ROM (just a custom recovery, which you will find useful if only for its extended features like Nandroid backup and additional wipes being available). As for why it's not possible by "installing su": Vicious circle. To install `su`, you need root.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I understand correctly, I have to wipe all data by this installation, isn't it? Have I a possibility to just root without wiping the device?

Comment: I have no Nexus device, so I cannot say for sure. But AFAIK the "oem unlock" part is only required if you plan to install custom ROMs – rooting itself should not require this (I've rooted my *Milestone 2* and my *Optimus 4X*, and never did an "oem unlock" – but it might depend on device and rooting strategy).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can root it without installing a custom ROM. [The rooting instructions on this site](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/37760/12442) just tell you to install a custom recovery, which can install `su` for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just a question: I see, that I need to install a flash, and this is what I don't want... Can I just apply the step 7?

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I tried with the HowTo ([How do I root my Nexus 7?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/37760/16575)) and now I have a rooted Nexus 7!
Well, I discovered, the "oem unlock" is not necessary, since the device was already unlocked... :)

Thank you all for your help!

Greetings
Luca, with a rooted Nexus! :)