# TWRP and CWM unable to mount Nexus 7 filesystem

Tags: rooting

I'm trying to root an unlocked Nexus 2013 Wifi. TWRP and CWM are unable to mount /data, /cache, or /system in recovery mode. TWRP reports internal storage of 0 MB. The system boots normally outside of recovery mode.

A soft-bricked restore with WUG didn't fix it. I've tried manually flashing TWRP and CWM with fastboot in VMWare Ubuntu, WUG in VMWare Windows 7, and in OS X, but the issue persists.

Comment: The partitions you listed are not mounted by default. On TWRP, select Mount, enable MTP, and enable the partitions

Comment: Could you please add this as an answer @TheBro21?

Comment: When I did that the partitions couldn't be checked. I found a solution to this issue on xda-developers (posted answer below).

Comment: @Sphinges That's maybe because you flashed a wrong recovery of
some other Nexus 7 variant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the partitions mounted by using the TWRP recovery image [posted here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-7-2013/nexus-7-2013-qa/mount-recovery-t3064562), I then followed the simple [rooting instructions here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37760/how-do-i-root-my-nexus-7).

Answer (score 1):

On TWRP (not sure bout CWM), only Data is mounted by default. You have to mount it with the mount option. Be sure to enable MTP (mount point) just in case